# Quick way to express percent from negative interval

Tags: percentages

I have some data which looks like this:

I get a number in the -6/+4 range and I need to express it with percent.
If I get 4 of course the result is 100%, If I get -6 is 0%, etc.

Is there a quick formula I can use to obtain the percent value of, say, -3.25?

Comment: I'm not sure if got the question, but your interval can be shifted in the interval $[0,10]$, now you multiply by $10$ and you get the percentage. Summarizing, take $x\in [-6,4]$ then your percentage is $((x+6)\cdot 10 )\%$.

Comment: Say I have a `-4.5/+4.5` range and I get a `0` value. Shouldn't that be equal to `50%`? With you formula I get `45%`. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x \in [-6, 4]$ the function
$$p(x) = \frac{x+6}{10}$$
is what you are looking for. You should note however that this gives numbers between $0$ and $1$. If you want the actual percentages, just use the function
$$q(x) = p(x) * 100 = 10 (x + 6)$$
instead.

In general for an interval $[a, b]$ you can use the formulas
$$p(x) = \frac {x-a} {b-a}$$
and
$$q(x) = 100 * p (x) = 100 * \frac {x-a} {b-a}$$

Comment: Please see my comment to the original question, how does this work in the case of a `0` value in a `-4.5/+4.5` interval?

Comment: @JesseP I edited my answer to include the formulas for the general case.

Comment: that's it, thank you.